# Pycharm docstring: How to add types into docstring with typing

Tags: python, pycharm, typing, docstring

In vscode, I install `autoDocstring` plugin, it can generate doc with types based on `Typing`. like below:

```py
def split_dataset(
        data: torch_geometric.data.Data,
        train: float = 0.1,
        test: float = 0.8,
        val: float = 0.1,
) -> tuple:
    """_summary_

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : torch_geometric.data.Data
        _description_
    train : float, optional
        _description_, by default 0.1
    test : float, optional
        _description_, by default 0.8
    val : float, optional
        _description_, by default 0.1

    Returns
    -------
    tuple
        _description_
    """
    pass
```

But in pycharm, I try to use docstring, it will not generate types automatically, like below:

```py
def split_dataset(
        data: torch_geometric.data.Data,
        train: float = 0.1,
        test: float = 0.8,
        val: float = 0.1,
) -> tuple:
    """
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    data : 
    train : 
    test : 
    val : 

    Returns
    -------

    """
    pass
```

Is there any way let pycharm do the same thing as vscode?

Comment: Why do you want to maintain the types both as annotations and in the docstring? Typically only one or the other used.

Comment: @ruohola I use docstring generate document, I think document should have more details, and I also use Typing and pylint to check code. So i think I need both of them

Comment: @bad_coder I think it's not, it just change the style of the docstring, but not custom the variable type

Comment: @MikuShaneG it is, and [there are at least a dozen duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocstring%5D+%5Bpycharm%5D+stub+type&searchOn=3)

Answer (score 1):

There's only a semi-automatic way to do this in PyCharm. Most of the docstring stub can be generated automatically, but you need to provide the types.

There's an official example on how to do this [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html#example)

TL;DR

```
    1. Press ⌘ + , and go to Editor | General | Smart Keys.

    2. Select the Insert type placeholders checkbox in the Smart Keys page of the editor settings.

    3. Place the caret at the function name, and press ⌥ ⏎.

    4. In the list of intention actions that opens, choose Insert documentation string stub. PyCharm creates a documentation stub, according to the selected docstring format, with the type specification, collected during the debugger session.
```

And then, manually specify the desired types.